# Error when upgrading civicrm for wordpress with wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, cli

In order to upgrade CiviCRM for WordPress from the command line on a remote server, I just installed wp-cli following the instructions at https://wp-cli.org/.

When I execute:

```
wp civicrm upgrade --zipfile ../Downloads/civicrm-5.48.0-wordpress.zip
```

I get a warning and an error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/home/myhome/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/wp-cli//civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myhome/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/wp-cli/civicrm.php on line 946

The upgrade process involves - 
1. Backing up current CiviCRM code as => /home/myhome/www/../backup/plugins/20220412055134/civicrm
2. Backing up database as => /home/myhome/www/../backup/plugins/20220412055134/civicrm.sql
3. Unpacking tarfile to => /home/myhome/www/wp-content/plugins/
4. Executing civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 just as a browser would.

Do you really want to continue? [y/n] y

Success: 1. Code backed up.
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myftpuser-001.privatesql' (115)" when trying to connect
```

I wonder if someone could give me an idea of a workaround for this problem.

Comment: I concur, this has failed for me as well.   I use an external file to get wp-cli to use `civicrm` from a different location since as soon as we remove the plugin we lose the needed file.  But I see this fails on 5.48.0.  Can you report an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment from Kevin Cristiano above, the WP-CLI commands for `upgrade` and `restore` seem to be broken in versions of CiviCRM since the `civicrm.settings.php` file was moved out of the CiviCRM plugin directory. Let's track progress on [the issue you opened](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/123) and leave this here as a signpost for others.